# Ankhsvn Subversion migration

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2008, solution, ankhsvn, working-copy

I have been given a "Working Copy" of several large projects that need to be subversioned to a new server. Now this is the problem.

```
Repository UUID '54266b8e-1acc-cf4b-8b36-8565631da9a7' 
doesn't match expected UUID 'b6ccde84-53ce-7c4c-9e5d-941e3d0c9f2b'
```

The working copy gives me an error when I try to commit it to another repository telling me that the GUID does not match the expected. I have tried to look up the problem but with no working solution for me.

Later I attempted to remove all the .svn files but that didn't seem to solve the problem.

I am not interrested in the subversion history. All I want is to create a new repository directory and start versioning my work on the project. How would I go about doing this? I have no idea how to work with AnkhSvn in detail and also cannot find any means to use command line options with it. Or is this another plugin for Ankhsvn? Can anyone help me with these issues?

Note: I do not have a copy of the original repository or it's settings as it appears that everything else was deleted over a year ago.

Where/how can I work with Anksvn commandlines? Where can I even find it? I have found commands but have no idea where to work with them. Why can I not just commit them to another repository? All the files return an error that they are locked? Completely confused with the whole subversion ordeal.

Comment: What's the issue? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically it wouldn't let me commit to a new repository or switch to a new repository. But your answer solved my problem. I can't believe I overlooked hidden files. :I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove `.svn` directory in the working copy.

   If the working copy is of SVN 1.6 or earlier format then all of it's folders contain hidden `.svn` directory. If it's of SVN 1.7 then the working copy has only one `.svn` directory at the root.
2. `svn add` the former working copy to the repository.
3. `svn commit`.

Comment: *sigh* I knew it was that easy. Time for friday. Also, much thanks for the quick reply.